# Excel VBA put a value in cell A and cell B will change automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to ask what is the best way for put a value in cell A and cell B will change automatically? For example: the condition is when cell A is "food" and after typing food in cell A ,cell B will automatically input the value as "burger" 
Any idea to do this in vba?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with either VBA or a formula.

VBA:

Right click on the tab and choose View Code:

Paste this in:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 1 Then 'Check the user entered data into column A
    If UCase(Target.Text) = "FOOD" Then Target.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "Burger" 'Update 1 cell to the right of the cell the user modified (called Target) if the cell text is "Food"
End If
End Sub
```

Excel Formula:

`=IF(A1="FOOD","Burger","")`

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this.  It will depend on how many references that you will need to update.  If there are only a few say less than 5 then you could use an `IIF` or `CHOOSE` function directly in the cell.  if there is a longer list then `VLOOKUP` is a good choice.  Now this just assumes that there is a one-to-one relationship between values.  If you type in food, is there the possibility of multiple results like 'Burger', 'Pizza', etc. then you could use a Data Validation to present a list of possible values.

Now if you want to go the VBA route, then you can create a function that takes a range, interprets the data, then returns a value.

See Dan Donoghue's answer for a good example

Comment: Nice point re: more data points, `VLOOKUP` would be my weapon of choice for a large number of options :).

Comment: Thanks @DanDonoghue. I like the example you gave as well :)

Comment: Thank you both of you. I didnt know vlookup will work in this case. I think i will pick vlookup because i got a list to reference

Comment: If this is the case you should unmark mine as the correct answer and mark Nathan's as the correct one :).

Comment: I think he gave a good idea on how to do this but you have answer my question directly with example